# Can I supply two different voltages with the same boost converter?

Tags: power-supply, power, boost, buck-boost

I have a VFD matrix display that needs both 90V and 70V to power on. I already designed a boost converter that will give me the 90V.

I was wondering if I can just put a voltage divider at the output to get the 70V.

I need 41ma and 21mA for the 90V and 70V inputs respectively.

Comment: How much current does the 70 V supply on the VFD matrix display need?

Comment: Voltage dividers aren't very useful for *supplying* power. How much current is drawn on the 70V input?  How much does it change?  What is the tolerance?  There are very cheap adjustable linear regulators that will handle those voltages if you only need a few mA; for more current, I would probably add a second boost converter.

Comment: I need 41mA and 21mA respectively. The resistors I have are 1% tolerance. I simultated my boost converter on ltpsice with the voltage divider, and I'm getting almost 80mA.

Comment: Have you considered a 1 W 20 V Zener diode? Not efficient but very simple. How tight voltage tolerance do you need on your 70 V supply?

Comment: @winny Not very tight, I have around a 20V window for both inputs

Comment: If you have a 20 volt window for both supplies then run them both from 80 volts.

Comment: 20V drop x 21 mA ~+ 400 mW. You have enough power to do this. It's entirely your choice whether to do it. It's low cost and simple compared to alternatives and reliable if designed properly. The loss is about 8% of your total energy use [(20x21)/(41x90 + 70x21) ]  . Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resistive divider is almost never the tool you want for supplying power.

What I would do, personally, is use a multiple-output flyback converter; the high voltages used by vacuum tube devices typically don't need very tight regulation, so the poor regulation you get from that (only one output can be held in accurate regulation) is probably tolerable.

You could also take your 90 V supply and use a linear regulator to drop it down to 70 V--this could be a high-voltage series regulator, or something as simple as a 20 V zener diode. You'd be dissipating about half a watt, which isn't nothing, but it's not a lot either unless this is a power-sensitive project. And if you're using a VFD it's probably not power-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage dividers made of 2 series resistors from the power rail to ground are commonly used when negligible amounts of current are needed by the circuit requiring a voltage lower than the power rail. A voltage reference input to a processor's Analog to Digital Converter is a good example. For circuits requiring more then negligible amounts of current, a voltage divider is difficult to justify. And for circuits requiring varying amounts of current over time, a voltage divider is likely a bad choice. Also, by its nature, a voltage divider wastes energy as current will always be flowing through the 2 series resistors.

Comment: Would 41mA and 21mA be negligible? I simulated my circuit with the voltage divider, and I'm getting roughly 80mA going through the output, which should be enough for the 62mA I need collectively. Does this mean it would be a valid design choice?

Comment: @MXVG "negligible" generally means "less than a handful of μA". You're orders of magnitude beyond that. But it depends on what you're actually doing and how much power you can afford to waste.

Comment: 21mA is not negligible in this application. I would use a linear regulator; 420mW power dissipation isn't great but it's simpler than another boost converter. A TO-92 package could handle it, but I'd be more comfortable with something a bit bigger and designed for heat dissipation. Just make sure you electrically insulate your heatsink if necessary.

Comment: @vir Using a linear regulator was something I considered, but I couldn't find a regulator that converts ~13V to 70V or 90V.

Comment: Linear regulators can only reduce the input voltage; use it to drop your 90V down to 70V.

Comment: @MXVG, I didn't say you shouldn't use a voltage divider. But I tried to gave you enough reasons not to. If this is a 1 time project, save your self any future problems and add in a second buck power supply. They should not add much cost to the project. That said, why are you not using a Vacuum Florescent Display with its own built in power supply and driver board?  This is what I do all the time when I use a VFD.

Answer (score 1):

Loss in a linear 90v to 70V dropper at 21 mA
= 20V drop x 21 mA ~+ 400 mW.

You say have enough power from your converter to do this.
It's entirely your choice whether to do it.
It's low cost and simple compared to alternatives and reliable if designed properly.

The loss is about 8% of your total energy use [(20x21)/(41x90 + 70x21) ] .
Low cost, simple, reliable, modest energy loss - sounds reasonable.